# artificial neural network for vehicular speed prediction based on volume

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I an trying to develop a neural network for vehicular speed prediction. my question is how can i train neural network with many input output combination of data?

Answer (score 1):

I think **LSTM based RNN** network having series of image data with a speed label, can be useful for training such model and you can try if you get some data set. Please do share your result as well.